# Showing a functor from a k-algebra to the zero set of an ideal is representable

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

I am trying to understand the above passage from Milne's "Basic Theory of Affine Group Schemes", but I'm confused about the statement "the n-tuples $(a_1,...,a_n)$ that arise from homomorphisms are exactly those in the zero-set of $\mathfrak{a}$". I assume this is using some property of coordinate rings, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milne is just saying that if $f:A=k[X_1,\cdots,X_n]/\mathfrak{a}\to R$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism, then it is specified by $f(X_1),\cdots,f(X_n)$, and we must have that if $P(X_1,\cdots,X_n)\in\mathfrak{a}$, then $P(f(X_1),\cdots,f(X_n))=0$ in $R$, which is simply a condition of being well-defined. (This process is reversible too - given $n$ elements $r_1,\cdots,r_n\in R$ which satisfy all the equations in $\mathfrak{a}$, you get a $k$-homomorphism $A\to R$ by sending $X_i\mapsto r_i$.)

Comment: Can you expand on how it’s a condition of being well defined? I’m not seeing it

Comment: @jasone if you have a ring map $A/I\to B$, this is equivalent to a ring map $A\to B$ such that $I\mapsto 0$ by the first isomorphism theorem for rings. If you have a ring map $A\to B$ where $I$ does not map to zero, then there is no possible way to produce a well-defined map $A/I\to B$ which fits as $A\to A/I\to B$, since different representatives for a class $a+I \in A/I$ will map to different places.

Answer (score 1):

Question: "I am trying to understand the above passage from Milne's "Basic Theory of Affine Group Schemes", but I'm confused about the statement "the n-tuples (a1,...,an) that arise from homomorphisms are exactly those in the zero-set of a". I assume this is using some property of coordinate rings, but I'm not sure what."

Answer: Let $A$ be a fixed base ring, let $B$ be a commutative $A$-algebra  and let $A[x_1,..,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ independent variables $x_1,..,x_n$ over $A$

By definition there s a 1-1 correspondence between the set of maps of $A$-algebras

$$f:A[x_1,..,x_n] \rightarrow B$$

and the set of $n$-tuples $(b_1,..,b_n) \in B^n$ where $B^n:=B \oplus \cdots \oplus B$ is the direct sum of $B$ with itself $n$ times. This correspondence maps a ring homomorphism $f$ to the $n$ elements $(f(x_1),..,f(x_n))$ with $f(x_i)$ in $B$ for $i=1,..,n$. If $I:=(g_1,..,g_k) \subseteq A[x_1,..,x_n]$ is an ideal generated by $k$ polynomials $g_i$, let $R:=A[x_j]/I$ be the quotient ring. It follows the set of maps of $A$-algebras

$$f: R \rightarrow B$$

equals the set of $n$-tuples $(b_1,..,b_n) \in B^n$ with $g_j(b_1,..,b_n)=0$.
Using this construction and the Yoneda lemma you may view a scheme as a functor on the category of $A$-algebras with values in the category of sets. An affine group scheme $h_G$ in this language becomes a representable functor

$$h_G(-): \underline{A-algebras} \rightarrow \underline{Groups}.$$

This is the point of view you find discussed in a modern treatment of the theory of group schemes and representations (see the books of Demazure/Gabriel/Jantzen etc).
In the classical EGA/SGA book series on algebraic geometry you find the same construction.

Note: There are some "set theoretical issues" with "the language of representable functors" and the Yoneda lemma. You end up studying "non standard set theory" and "non small categories". Grothendieck wrote something on this and you should read this before reading about representable functors.